# How to link two pandas data frames for a simple calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes named *df* and *cleaned_data*.

- *df* holds information about stock closing prices for 9 different stocks and their respective dates
- *cleaned_data* holds news articles for the 9 stocks along with their ticker, date and whether the article was posted after 4pm (when markets close)

I am struggling to calculate the percentage change in price associated with each article and its respective date. (Eventually, I aim to use sentiment analysis to predict the effects of stock news articles on price movements.)

**Calculation rules:**

If the article was posted after 4pm (column `after4`==1), I would like the %change in price to be:

`adj close(t+1) - adj close(t)/adj close(t) *100`

If it is before 4pm:

`adj close(t) - adj close(t-1)/adj close(t-1) *100.`

**Example data:**

cleaned_data data frame looks like this:

```
             id       text                                              Date       after4
symbols             
NFLX    1.01972E+18 Senate wants emergency alerts to go out throug...   2018-07-18  1
NFLX    1.01969E+18 Netflix NFLX just released quarterly 10-Q. Qu...    2018-07-18  1
NFLX    1.01969E+18 RT Excluding FAANG Stocks The S&amp;P Would B...    2018-07-18  1
NFLX    1.01969E+18 RT Here is where FANG was trading the last ti...    2018-07-18  1
NFLX    1.01969E+18 RT Trader Takeaways 7.18.18 by Focus on SPY ...     2018-07-18  1
```

df data frame looks like this:

```
        Date        NFLX         MTB        GPS         ES       MOMO  \
2 2018-07-16  400.480011  160.774506  26.513777  55.796215  42.161884   
3 2018-07-17  379.480011  161.137909  26.891514  55.635551  43.164043   
4 2018-07-18  375.130005  166.856628  27.125355  55.304787  43.335030   
5 2018-07-19  364.230000  165.221344  27.620012  55.909626  42.347126   

         MAT         HON         ESS  GRPN  
2  44.696285  134.337509  224.523422  4.70  
3  45.651787  136.255325  221.290680  4.64  
4  46.597641  136.860947  220.187729  4.72  
5  45.043739  135.383591  221.100479  4.75
```

I am trying create a new column in cleaned_data holding the %change in price, however I am new to python and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Hello @tmtravers, in your calculation, what do you mean by `adj`, and `close(t)`? I can't match this to the columns in your data frame. Is t=date and t+1=date+1day? From what I understand, have a look at pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) methods.

Comment: Hi @Kim, yes sorry adj close is just the adjusted close price, which is the data in the data frame. t meaning the date and t+1 being the date + 1 day etc.

Comment: @tmatravers In which df you want to calculate the % , what is the connection between  cleaned_data and df.

Comment: @HietshKumar I would like the % calculation to be in the cleaned_data data frame, in a separate column. And the connection between the two data frames is the date of the news article in cleaned_data, and the date column in df which corresponds to the date of the closing price. thanks